# Find and Replace Values in Consecutive Cells Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to replace values in three adjacent columns by row using values in another table. So far I've modified the code from this answer: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/745557-visual-basic-applications-find-replace-multiple-values-multiple-cells-print.html

I want the names under columns A, B, and C to be searched for in columns G, H and I and replaced by the values listed under columns D, E and F (there are more values so the code needs to link to the columns, not just that particular range). I would want this code to only change the sequence if all three values in column A, B, and C match all three values of G, H, and I.

The code kind of works for the first two columns, G and H (not sure why it won't on the column I), but if I have the same values in column A but different values in column B it isn't identifying that it needs to find the three adjacent cells together, it will find what is in column A and replace the value in column G with column D's value but it stops after that and replaces nothing else.

My code:

```
Sub test()

Dim NumV, AlphaV As String
Dim irow As Long

irow = Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until irow = 0
    TskOwn = Cells(irow, 1)
    NewTskOwn = Cells(irow, 4)
    TskSup = Cells(irow, 2)
    NewTskSup = Cells(irow, 5)
    TskIni = Cells(irow, 3)
    NewTaskIni = Cells(irow, 6)

If Cells(irow, 7) = TskOwn And Cells(irow, 8) = TskSup And Cells(irow, 9) = TskIni Then
    Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = (34)
    Columns(7).Replace What:=TskOwn, Replacement:=NewTskOwn, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = (22)
    Columns(8).Replace What:=TskSup, Replacement:=NewTskSup, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = (12)
    Columns(9).Replace What:=TskIni, Replacement:=NewTskIni, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
End If

irow = irow - 1
Loop


End Sub
```

What I have:

```
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| A      | B      | C       | D     | E     | F     | G      | H      | I       |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| Ty     | Sheri  | Richard | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Ty     | Sheri  | Richard |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| Rachel | Sheila | Sheila  | Name4 | Name5 | Name2 | Rachel | Sheila | Sheila  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| Rachel | Bob    | Paul    | Name6 | Name7 | Name1 | Ty     | Sheri  | Richard |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Sarah  | Kyle   | Robert  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Rachel | Bob    | Paul    |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Ty     | Sheri  | Richard |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Rachel | Sheila | Sheila  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Rachel | Bob    | Paul    |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Ty     | Sheri  | Richard |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Ty     | Sheri  | Richard |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Rachel | Sheila | Sheila  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Ty     | Sheri  | Richard |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Sarah  | Kyle   | Robert  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Rachel | Sheila | Sheila  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
```

What I want:

```
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| A      | B      | C       | D     | E     | F     | G     | H     | I      |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Ty     | Sheri  | Richard | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name1 | Name2 | Name3  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Rachel | Sheila | Sheila  | Name4 | Name5 | Name2 | Name4 | Name5 | Name2  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Rachel | Bob    | Paul    | Name6 | Name7 | Name1 | Name1 | Name2 | Name3  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Sarah | Kyle  | Robert |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name6 | Name7 | Name1  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name1 | Name2 | Name3  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name4 | Name5 | Name2  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name6 | Name7 | Name1  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name1 | Name2 | Name3  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name1 | Name2 | Name3  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name4 | Name5 | Name2  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name1 | Name2 | Name3  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Sarah | Kyle  | Robert |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name4 | Name5 | Name2  |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

What I'm getting:

```
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| A      | B      | C       | D     | E     | F     | G     | H     | I      |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Ty     | Sheri  | Richard | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name1 | Name2 |        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Rachel | Sheila | Sheila  | Name4 | Name5 | Name2 | Name4 | Name5 |        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Rachel | Bob    | Paul    | Name6 | Name7 | Name1 | Name1 | Name2 |        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Sarah | Kyle  | Robert |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name4 | Bob   | Paul   |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name1 | Name2 |        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name4 | Name5 |        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name4 | Bob   | Paul   |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name1 | Name2 |        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name1 | Name2 |        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name4 | Name5 |        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name1 | Name2 |        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Sarah | Kyle  | Robert |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|        |        |         |       |       |       | Name4 | Name5 |        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Any help would be appreciated! Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to try reformatting, that, it's pretty whacky  https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

Comment: Thanks for the table generator!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub replaceNames()

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range("I1").End(xlDown).Row
    For j = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        If Cells(i, 7) = Cells(j, 1) And Cells(i, 8) = Cells(j, 2) And Cells(i, 9) = Cells(j, 3) Then
            Cells(i, 7) = Cells(j, 4)
            Cells(i, 8) = Cells(j, 5)
            Cells(i, 9) = Cells(j, 6)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!